# OpenNLP find() method

Tags: java, text, text-mining, opennlp

At the moment im trying to find names inside a document. Im using the following method to find the names:

`find(String[] tokens)`

I also found this method below:

```
find(String[] tokens,String[][] additionalContext)
```

what can I do with this method and how do I use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME apidocs](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.3/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/namefind/NameFinderME.html#find-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A:A-):

> ```
> public Span[] find(String[] tokens, String[][] additionalContext)
> ```
>
> Generates name tags for the given sequence, typically a sentence,
>   returning token spans for any identified names.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `tokens` - an array of the tokens or words of the sequence, typically    a sentence.
> - **`additionalContext` - features which are based on context outside of    the sentence but which should also be used.**
>
> Returns:
>       an array of spans for each of the names identified.

That being said, consider your tokens are:

```
String[] tokens = { "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "adipiscing", "elit" };
```

But you also want to take into account the following features, "*which are based on context outside of the sentence but which should also be used*":

```
String[][] additionalContext = { 
    { "nullam", "fermentum", "justo", "non", "leo", "rhoncus", "blandit" },
    { "phasellus", "at", "diam", "mattis", "arcu", "congue", "consequat" },
    { "integer", "at", "tincidunt", "turpis", "eget", "pulvinar", "nisl" } };
```

This way you can call `find(tokens, additionalContext)`.

Note that, according to the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/opennlp/blob/master/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/namefind/NameFinderME.java#L110), `find(String[] tokens)` is actually `find(tokens, EMPTY)` (and `String[][] EMPTY = new String[0][0]`).